# Ds4 controller, problems connecting to pc

Tags: pc, ps4, controllers

Ok, so i have tried literally everything that other forums, other posts, and literally what my witch doctor have told me, so i have taken the messure of going to the gods of the internet myself and try to see if someone can solve my problem.

So i have a DS4 playstation controller (2 in fact, and the same problem consists with them both). When i use them for my playstation, there is not a single thing wrong with them, neither with bluetooth or with USB-wired. But as soon as i want to connect them to my pc, my controller couldn't connect properly. it was just flashing orange, showing it was charging, but no connection.

For a long time, actually many years, i used DS4Windows as my ds4 controller tool, but all of the sudden, it didn't want to get connection. So i tried installing some other software called SCPToolkit. It worked for the most parts, but for some reason it would start vibrating uncontrollable, even with vibration turned off.

I then took to the internet to uncover this uncertain problem of mine, and i found people talking about the HID driver, talking about the unit under Devices and Printers, i saw people talking about blinking blue lights, which all lead to my problems.

I have tried reinstalling drivers, i have tried reinstalling the toolkits, i have tried disabling the driver, and enabling it again, since people said it for some reason was turned off for them, and that fixed everything, but it was never deactivated for me.

Then all of the sudden, my controller under Devices and Printers had gone from a controller device, to a sound device. Now consider me puzzled and i took to the net again, yet the fixes people suggested, which might as well have led to the salvation of the entire world, according to people, did not fix mine. i took to the messure to just delete the whole device itself, and reinstalling it, upon which it again, became a controller device.

Yet upon this, it did not fix my problems at all. Next i did, i tried pressing the reset button on the back of the controller, which now have lead it to just constant blinking its blue delighted light, upon which i have read, "just press the reset button, and that should fix it" which i now have done like 3 times, and was what made me be stuck in this position as i am.

I have read almost every single forum post on every forum talking about this problem with USB-connected controller to pc, but none of the solutions would seem to grant me my wish.

All i want is to play some of my games with my controller, but it seems that the entire world is neglecting this wish.

And now, benevolent gods of the internet, i beg of thee, please soothe this problem of mine with a solution to my problems.

Comment: Have you tried to connect your controller via bluetooth? Windows might recognize it that way.

Comment: problem is, that my pc does not have bluetooth, so i can't do that. if i could do that it would've fixed alot of my other problems i had earlier before this happened, but i can't

Comment: Something tells me that you deleted the generic controller driver. A DualShock 4 reports 3 different devices that can be seen on the Device Manager: a controller (HID-compliant game controller), an audio output (Headset Earphone (Wireless Controller)) and an audio input (Headset Microphone (Wireless Controller)). I checked this with a DualShock v2, I'm not sure if is the same as a DualShock v1.